# Using the max() function for listing total number of column in sql

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table in SQL called AlbumSongs that holds an AlbumID, a SongID a TrackNumber, where the value of TrackNumber is an int. I also have a table called Albums that has an AlbumID, AlbumName, and other columns. I am trying to list all of the Albums in the table and the total number of tracks each album has. However whenever I run the query, I end up just getting one album and giant sum of the TrackNumbers.

```
Select Albums.AlbumTitle, Max(AlbumSongs.TrackNumber) from Albums
join AlbumSongs on Albums.AlbumID=AlbumSongs.AlbumID
order by AlbumTitle;
```

If someone could please help me with this error I would appreciate it

Comment: I would expect this to return 1 result with the maximum track number - not a giant sum of track numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group the results

```
Select Albums.AlbumTitle, Max(AlbumSongs.TrackNumber) from Albums
join AlbumSongs on Albums.AlbumID=AlbumSongs.AlbumID
group by Albums.AlbumID
order by AlbumTitle;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I just have one more question. If I were to write this same query, but instead only return the albums with tracks less than 12, where would I insert that? Next to the Max statement or in the Group By statement you just provided?

Comment: Try this _Select Albums.AlbumTitle, Max(AlbumSongs.TrackNumber) MaxTrack 
from Albums
join AlbumSongs on Albums.AlbumID=AlbumSongs.AlbumID
group by Albums.AlbumID 
having MaxTrack < 12
order by AlbumTitle;_

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help I appreciate it